# simple javascript regex to match url pattern help needed

Tags: javascript, regex

I've never been good with regex syntax, can someone help me out to to check if a URL matches a specific structure in my example?

The .* can be anything including /-_# etc, the 0-9 would be any number length (ex 1993334).

```
var pattern = new RegExp('/articles/[0-9]/[.*]');
if (pattern.test(document.location.href)) {
    // match found
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\/articles\/[0-9]+\/.*
```

So, escape the slashes, and use `+` to specify there has to be "one or more" of the preceding element.

Comment: that did the trick! will accept your answer when the time delay is up

Comment: @Joe: the time delay expired ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [0-9]+ instead of [0-9] and use the slashes correctly..

```
var pattern = new RegExp(\/articles\/[0-9]+\/(.*));
if (pattern.test(document.location.href)) {
    // match found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already gotten your answer, so that's no problem, but just like Cerbrus told you, I'll explain why the regex didn't work.

```
new RegExp('/articles/[0-9]/[.*]');
```

The `/articles/` part is completely correct.

You've had an idea about the `[0-9]` (any digit), but you've specified that "this appears only once". By adding a `+` you specify "one or more", just like if you added a `*` it'd mean "zero or more".

In your last match `[.*]`, you're matching "any character" (`.`) repeated "zero or more" (`*`) times, and therefore an URL of `/articles/2/` (without anything after this) could be matched, and I assume this is unwanted behaviour.

To be completely precise, you might even use a regex of

`^/articles/[0-9]+/.+$`

Whereas the `^` means "this has to be the start" and `$` meaning "this has to be the end".

If you don't include these, an URL like `/non-relevant-url/articles/123/my-article/whatever/foo/bar` could be matched (and you might not want to match if it starts with `/non-relevant-url` - the `^` fixes this.)

**Note:** The `$` isn't really necessary in this example, seeing as you end it with a "match everything past this point", but I included it so you'd know what it means (as it's just as useful to know as `^`)

Hope it gave you a tiny insight in regex, which once learned is incredibly powerful.

Comment: Actually, `[.*]` matches exactly 1 `.` character, or 1 `*`. It's the same as `\.|*`